# how to find items on a table Grid using WATIN

Tags: watin

I am having some issues trying to find item on a table - it's either null or I am getting an array out of bounds exception. This is what i am trying to do.

This is sample html that I am parsing from the page....

```
<table id="ctl00__defaultCont__ctrlHeader__ctrlHeader_p_Providerd33">
<tr>
    <td class="w90 ta-right lbl">
                        <span>Provider ID</span>
                    </td>
    <td class="fieldWithNoBorderClass">
                        <div id="ob_iT_providerIDContainer" class="ob_iTCN" style="width:220px;"><div class="ob_iTL"></div><div class="ob_iTR"></div><div class="ob_iTC"><input name="ctl00$_defaultContent$_ctrlHeader$_ctrlHeader$_providerID" type="text" value="P13040620" id="ctl00__defaultContent__ctrlHeader__ctrlHeader__providerID" class="ob_iTIE" /></div><div class="ob_iCallbackScript" style="display:none;"></div></div>
                    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is what I started out with:

I am basically trying to find the PROVIDER ID. For example...

```
Table table = browser.Table(Find.ById("ctl00__defaultContent__ctrlHeader__ctrlHeader_p_Provider3"));
                        TableRowCollection tableRows = table.TableRows;
                        TableRow row = tableRows[3];
                        ElementCollection rowData = row.Elements;

                        string name = rowData[0].OuterText;
                        string membername = rowData[1].OuterText;
```

Answer (score 2):

I do something like this, and it works on one of my projects. Maybe this will give you a clue.

NOTE: Watin table access is VERY slow.

```
      Table table = browser.Table("ctl00_defaultContent_ctrlHeader__ctrlHeader_p_Provider3");
      if (table == null)
      {
         DebugLog("Could not find table");
         throw new Exception("Results table missing.");
      }
      TableRow tr = table.TableRows[3];
      while( tr != null)
      {
        string words = tr.TableCells[1].Text;
        tr = (TableRow)tr.NextSibling;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to search the item one by one:

```
Table table = browser.Table(Find.ById("ctl00_defaultContent_ctrlHeader__ctrlHeader_p_Provider3")); 
  for (int i = 0; i < table.TableBodies[bodyIndex].TableRows.Count; i++)
      {
           if (table.TableBodies[0].OwnTableRows[i].TableCells[headerNameColumn].Text ==             "Provider id...")
           {
              // do something
           }
      }
```